# My SD card is acting up, how can I recover what's in it?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, data-recovery

Last night, on my phone, I was trying to copy a file from one folder in the SD to another folder. But whenever I tap paste, the SD card would disconnect (I see a "this operation could not be completed" message when I try to open a folder). I'd have to either restart the phone or force stop the explorer app in order to access the SD card, but then, again as soon as I paste, it disconnects. I couple of restarts and I get a message "SD card currputed  fix?" (or something like that).

I took out the card, put it in a card reader and plugged it into the computer. It mounted normally and I could see my files. I started uploading its contents to the cloud but one folder was taking too long so I opted to back up to local drive. But then all of a sudden the SD card dismounts, I guess similar to what it was doing in the phone. A few more such attempts and now I see the drive name changed to strange characters.

What can I do to extract/recover everything from it? I remember doing something similar a while back (thanks the Alecxs) on Linux, but it was for getting my files out of a corrupted adopted SD card...can't remember the steps for the life of me. It was very involved (relative to copy and past on Windows), but WELL worth it.

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: this card is dead, don't use it anymore. you can try gddrescue to get image, or try on PC straight from card reader. but I guess it will disconnect again

Comment: https://www.klennet.com https://www.z-a-recovery.com https://www.runtime.org